# How to create MQTT broker in NestJS 8

Tags: node.js, nest

I'm trying to create an **MQTT** broker in **NestJS**, so I'm following the official doc [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/mqtt). However I have the impression that this doc is not up to date anymore because with Nest version 8 `MicroserviceOptions` doesn't exist so I don't know by what to replace it.

```
const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, {
  transport: Transport.MQTT,
  options: {
    url: 'mqtt://localhost:1883',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed `@nest/microservices`?

Try `npm i --save @nestjs/microservices` or `yarn add @nestjs/microservices` if you are using yarn

You should be able to import what you need

```js
import { Transport, MicroserviceOptions } from '@nestjs/microservices';
```